# Azure: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 10.0.0.4:3306

Tags: sockets, exception, azure-web-app-service, port, azure-mysql-database

I created a mysql database instance in North Europe, then a Web app there in
North Europe, via VS published in Azure and at startup I get an [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H85dw.png) as in the screenshot. Everything works locally in VS using this connection string, but not in Azure itself. If you disable the DB instance, the exception is the same, so the application does not connect to the DB at all. I have been suffering with this problem for 4 hours. The connection port to MySQL Azure does not change. [In the security settings in my opinion everything is fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thgdZ.png) The local mysql server that could theoretically occupy port 3306 is [disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwk06.png)

connectionString="Server=testing-db-srv2.mysql.database.azure.com; Port=3306; Database=testing-sys-azure; Uid= ###@testing-db-srv2; Pwd= ###; SslMode=Preferred;"

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/230012/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootx-x-x-x

Comment: Check your connection strings.

Comment: @JasonPan it corresponds to the string that is given in the example in the Azure portal: Server=testing-db-srv2.mysql.database.azure.com; Port=3306; Database={your_database}; Uid= ###@testing-db-srv2; Pwd={your_password}; SslMode=Preferred; It works locally in IIS

Answer (score 0):

Please check your appsettings.json file for any API endpoints that might need to be updated now that your app is on Azure. This is the most common cause for this type of error.